# Komodo Edit 8.5 tab settings

Tags: php, komodo, komodoedit

I use Komodo Edit 8.5 and I have problems with tabs. When I press tab key it jumps 8 characters instead of 4 which I use in preferences (Edit – Preferences - Indentation).

The "number of spaces per indent" is 4 and "Width of each tab character" is 4 too, so I don't understand where is the problem.

Everything appear fine (one tab is equal to 4 characters), but when I hit the tab key it jumps 8 characters. It seems it completely ignores my settings.

Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Komodo has a bug in the setting "Allow file contents to override tab settings"**. Here (in #1) is how to fix it such that you will no longer need to change the per-file settings:

1. Go to: Preferences->Editor->Indentation. **From this screen. Turn off "Allow file contents to override tab settings" as this is very buggy and can cause Komodo to over-ride your settings (hence the need to change the per-file-setting)**
2. From the same screen - change the "Number of Spaces per Indent" to 4
3. From the same screen - use the drop down to check the per-language tab settings for each file type you are editing
4. From the same screen - untick "Prefer tab characters over spaces" both in the upper section, and in the per-language section of this screen (be sure to check the drop down). The tab character settings appear to be buggy.

For currently open files, either close them all and re-open them, or do the following:

5. Right click inside the text of the file->Properties and Settings->Indentation (*or via Edit menu->Current File Settings; or via Code menu->Current File Settings*). The Indentation section needs to be changed on a per-file basis for currently open files.

All new files / or newly opened files will now open with the correct indent settings from now on due to change in #1.

-- More Info --

- Post by 'zaknafein' tipped me off to the real cause of problem in point #1: http://community.activestate.com/forum/komodo-edit-spaces-instead-tabs-how#comment-10135
- This one tipped me off to the problem in point #4 http://community.activestate.com/forum/buggy-indentation
- More discussion: http://community.activestate.com/forum/usability-indentation-settings-komodo-are-broken

Comment: Does not work for me. When I press 'tab' I get two(!) tabs. Well its on a mac. I suppose its a mac issue...

Answer (score 6):

You might also need to apply your changes in Code > Current File Settings > Indentation.

Comment: +1 - My Current File Setings "Number of Spaces per Indent" was set to 8. Changing that to 4 made my tab work as expected. Also as a note, the path is `Edit > Current File Settings > Editor > Indentation`

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the following option in the Editor=>Preferences=>Indentation menu:

- `Prefer Tab Characters over spaces`

> Komodo displays Tab characters wherever possible, according to the values specified in the Number of spaces per indent and the Width of each Tab character fields. When the 'Tab' key is pressed, Komodo inserts indentation up to the next indent width. If the new indentation is a multiple of the Tab width, Komodo inserts a Tab character. Example: With a Tab width of 8 and an indent width of 4, the first indent is 4 spaces, the second indent is a Tab character, and the third indent is a Tab character plus 4 spaces.

**References**

- [ActiveState Komodo: Configuring Indentation](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/8.5/prefs.html#Indentation_Features)